# Get data of table with some data from other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple table `visitor` and another table `visitor_tokens`.

SQL creation script of `visitor`:

```
CREATE TABLE `visitor` (
  `id` int(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
ALTER TABLE `visitor`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `phone_index` (`phone`);
ALTER TABLE `visitor`
  MODIFY `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
INSERT INTO `visitor` (`phone`) VALUES
('111111111');
```

SQL creation script of `visitor_tokens`:

```
CREATE TABLE `visitor_tokens` (
  `id` int(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `visitor` int(7) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE `visitor_tokens`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `visitor_tokens`
  MODIFY `id` int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
INSERT INTO `visitor_tokens` (`visitor`, `token`) VALUES
(1, 'abc_token'),
(1, 'xyz_token');
```

I want to get some data of visitor by `id`:
I want to get the phone number (`phone` column) and the visitor tokens (`visitor_tokens`.`token`). All - according to given `id`.

My current SQL script is: `SELECT visitor.phone, visitor_tokens.token FROM visitor JOIN visitor_tokens ON visitor_tokens.visitor=visitor.id WHERE id=1`. This gives me only the phone and the first token: `abc`. But I also want to get the tokens of the visitor from the second table. To get something like `[abc_token, xyz_token]`. How can I do it?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I edited my try. I don't know how to get within the `select` the tokens. Only the conditional `JOIN`

Comment: Does this work ? `select v.id,v.phone,vt.token from visitor_tokens vt JOIN visitor v where v.id=vt.id;`

Comment: @Dev-vruper you meant `v.id=vt.visitor`. Anyway, it gives me 2 rows instead of 1. Both are identical, except the `token` column. But I look for solution with only 1 row.

Comment: `But I also want to get the tokens of the visitor from the second table. ` this is what you are expecting right ? so it will return 2 rows as there are 2 tokens associated with id=1.

Comment: @Dev-vruper I got this: `SELECT visitor.id, GROUP_CONCAT(visitor_tokens.token) AS tokens FROM visitor JOIN visitor_tokens ON visitor_tokens.visitor=visitor.id WHERE visitor.id=1 LIMIT 1;` This returns 1 row only, with the two tokens separated by comma. BUT if there are no tokens, it fails. How to fix it, so also if there are no tokens to the visitor, then return `tokens` column as empty?

Comment: @Dev-vruper Read my solution. This is what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

So this is my solution (also recommend on reading the main comments):

```
SELECT visitor.phone, GROUP_CONCAT(visitor_tokens.token) AS tokens FROM visitor LEFT JOIN visitor_tokens ON visitor_tokens.visitor=visitor.id WHERE visitor.id=1 LIMIT 1;
```

It returns result regardless of missing visitor tokens (`LEFT JOIN`), and also if there are tokens - it returns the tokens separated by comma in one row.